# FreeType Text Rendering under DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx-11, freetype

At the moment i just want to render a single char with FreeType and DirectX 11.
But how can i create a "ID3D11ShaderResourceView" from FT_Bitmap?
I already tried "D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile" and "D3DX11CreateTextureFromFile" but both doesn't work.

Has someone a good tutorial or a code snippet for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`FT_Bitmap`](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Bitmap) is a bitmap already loaded into memory, you can't use the functions that create a texture from a file. Instead, you'll want to use a function to create a texture from memory.

You could use [`D3DXCreateShaderResourceViewFromMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476284(v=vs.85).aspx), however the D3DX library is deprecated. As mentioned on that page, you might want to instead use the [DirectXTK](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/) or [DirectXTex](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/) library to create a texture from memory.

Alternatively, you can create a D3D texture and shader resource view manually using [`ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476521(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476519(v=vs.85).aspx).

The only tricky part will be to determine which [`DXGI_FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173059(v=vs.85).aspx) to use. You will need to match it with the [`FT_Pixel_mode`](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Pixel_Mode) of the bitmap.